# Set form exposed filter default value

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Ajax form. Exposed filter with `-Any-`. In `hook_form_alter()` i write:

```
if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    if ($form_state['view']->name == 'machinery') {
        $form['field_producer_tid']['#options']['All'] = t('-All-');
    }
    $form['field_producer_tid']['#default_value'] = "All";
    dsm($form);
}
```

But default value is the second `<option>` from select list. Always. Any value which i assign is ignored. How should i set default value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://drupal.org/node/1239868 you will have to use some other hook.
You can try

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_build().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'machinery') {
    $view->filter['field_producer_tid']->value = "All";
  }
}
```

This way, you will be able to choose default value.

Comment: You're right. But in addition to this code needs `$view->exposed_input['field_producer_tid'] = "All";` Together they bring result. Thank you for help =) !!!

Comment: Another way: `Remember the last selection = true` + `$view->filter['field_producer_tid']->value = "All";` in `hook_views_pre_build`

Answer (score 3):

Just in case that you (like me at first) overread Df.fpm's comment on botanic_spark's answer,
the **complete and working answer** (as of 7.32) is as follows:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME') {
    $view->filter['FIELD_ID']->value = "All";
    $view->exposed_input['FIELD_ID'] = "All";
  }
}
```

Only with the addition of the second line it will work!

Answer (score 2):

The above solution will not allow you to switch between filters if it is a ajax view.
I found this solution, better solution might be available but this will work.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function HOOK_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name =='VIEW_NAME') {
    $q = drupal_get_query_parameters();
    $form_state['input']['FIELD_ID'] = 'ALL';
    if($q['FIELD_ID']) {
    $form_state['input']['field_7_step_refernce_tid'] = $q['FIELD_ID'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: According to [@Salmon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43930577) this answer works, but it's also giving the following error: `Notice: Undefined index` at the line that reads `if($q['field_location_tid']) {`.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to get this working by doing the following:

I changed the filter status value,

> $view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->handlers['filter']['status']->value

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_build().
 */
function my_module_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  // Check if the current view is the orders view.
  if ($view->name == 'commerce_backoffice_orders') {
    if($view->current_display == 'page_1') {
      if (empty($view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->handlers['filter']['status']->value)) {
        $view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->handlers['filter']['status']->value = 'pending';
      }
    }
    elseif ($view->current_display == 'page_2') {
      if (empty($view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->handlers['filter']['status']->value)) {
        $view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->handlers['filter']['status']->value = 'processing';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is working on **Drupal >= 8**

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-my-view-display') {
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    if (is_null($request->get('EXPOSED_FILTER_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME'))) {
      $form_state->setUserInput(['EXPOSED_FILTER_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME' => 'DEFAULT_VALUE']);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me:

default values can be passed in as URL query parameters. For example if the filter has a single value:

- /path/to/view?field_id=defaultvalue

If the filter can have multiple values:

- /path/to/view?field_id%5B%5D=defaultvalue